# Center a div vertically and horizontally amongst other inputs and divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, stylesheet

I already did a few search on this and it made me insane:

- I need to make the text "**CENTER & MIDDLE THIS**" centered in the area below the `textarea` and above the bottom of `.input` like this:

[image]

Code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/zqYUJ/2/

Right now it seems like it is middle align between the bottom of `input1` and `input`

Conditions:

1. We know `.input1 input` height is `30px`
2. I prefer to not specify the height of `textarea` but if we have to, that's less ideal but OK.
3. `.input` height and width is already specified in the code.
4. I also prefer not to use jQuery. I don't like "hardcode" the pixel position either because later on, the `textarea` height may change by jQuery depending how much text in it.

Help would be appreciate!!!

Comment: post your desired result mock

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/YsAuK/

Comment: I updated with the desired pic

Comment: try setting `margin:0 auto`, it will automatically adjust content according to the element boundries.

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/YsAuK/2/ But vertical centering is a problem.

Comment: @Antony: I tried to stay away from hardcoded pixel thing ;-) It could get messy later on when jQuery involved with other elements (i.e. changing height of textarea or new element inserted in, etc...)

Comment: I know I know. Haven't finished yet. Maybe someone else can help also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `dispaly:table-cell`

```
.input {
    height:300px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black; display:table
}
.input1 input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;     
}
.input2 textarea {
    width: 100%;    
}
.input3 {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; display:table-row;
    text-align:center;     
}
.input3 div {
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:auto 0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zqYUJ/42/)**

Comment: That works beautifully even when I change the `textarea` size. Thanks!!! --> http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/zqYUJ/48/

Answer (score 1):

Check out you updated fiddle :
just set `left` and `top`
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqYUJ/28/)

Comment: This one is same as Antony's where it is still not really vertical middle.

Comment: I am still working on it. This doesn't work as the text in red background is changed.

Comment: check updated fiddle...!! I thought you want in center of you main div

Comment: I like it to look like the image I just updated. Basically you see there is an area below the `textarea` and the bottom border of main div. It should middle align between those two.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your  '.input3 div' style like this. It may help...

```
  .input3 div {
     text-align: center;
     background: red;
     top: 50%;
     margin: 80px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it should be:

```
top: 50%;
left:27%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqYUJ/43/embedded/result/